# How to SELECT LIMIT in ASE 12.5? LIMIT 10, 10 gives syntax error?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

How can I `LIMIT` the result returned by a query in Adaptive Server IQ/12.5.0/0306?

The following gives me a generic error near LIMIT:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 10, 10;
```

Any idea why? This is my first time with this dbms

Comment: Not sure which syntax Sybase accepts, but that version is MySQL's invention I think. Try "LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10", or the  ridiculously verbose ANSI standard version, which is something like "FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS STARTING AT 10"

Comment: @IMSoP well none works. Version is from select @@version directly from the shell, is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sybase IQ uses *row_count* to limit the number of rows returned.

You will have to set the row count at the beginning of your statement and decide whether the statement should be TEMPORARY or not.

[ROW_COUNT](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/CIHBEAFD.htm)
[SET options](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/X315773.htm)

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you give me an example query to select 10 rows skipping the first 10?

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT` statement is not supported in Sybase IQ 12. I think there is not simple or clean solution, similarly like in old SQL server. But there are some approches that works for SQL server 2000 and should work also for Sybase IQ 12. I don't promise that queries below will work on copy&paste.

**Subquery**

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM mytable
WHERE Id NOT IN (
    SELECT TOP 10 Id FROM mytable ORDER BY OrderingColumn
)
ORDER BY OrderingColumn
```

Basically, it fetches 10 rows but also skips first 10 rows. To get this works, rows must be unique and ordering is important. Id cannot be more times in results. Otherwise you can filter out valid rows.

**Asc-Desc**

Another workaround depends on ordering. It uses ordering and fetches 10 rows for second page and you have to take care of last page (it does not work properly with simple formula page * rows per page).

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP 20 * -- (page * rows per page)
        FROM mytable
        ORDER BY Id
    ) AS t1
    ORDER BY Id DESC
) AS t2
ORDER BY Id ASC
```

**I've found some info about non working subqueries in FROM statement in ASE 12. This approach maybe is not possible.**

**Basic iteration**

In this scenario you can just iterate through rows. Let's assume id of tenth row  is 15. Then it will select next 10 rows after tenth row. Bad things happen when you will order by another column than Id. It is not possible.

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM mytable
WHERE Id > 15
ORDER BY Id
```

Here is article about another workarounds in SQL server 2000. Some should also works in similar ways in Sybase IQ 12.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6936/Paging-of-Large-Resultsets-in-ASP-NET

All those things are workarounds. If you can try to migrate on newer version.